# EWS Load a Deleted Task

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

> Tl;dr Using `Exchange Web Services`, I want to fully load a deleted `Task`
>   object in my client app, e.g. using the `Task.Bind()` method or similar.

Using Exchange Web Services, I'm performing a [`SyncFolderItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693003(v=exchg.80).aspx) call, which successfully returns all of the updated Task items I need to update / delete in my client system.

However, in the `ChangeCollection` returned, if the `ChangeType` is `ChangeType.Delete`, the item only contains minimal data (basically just the `ItemId`). To update my client system, I need to get an extended property stored with the Task in Exchange, which stores the corresponding local id for my client system (that I will have 'tagged' the Tasks with when creating them earlier).

Attempting to load the Task using the following code gives a '`The specified object was not found in the store`' error message.

```
'my extended custom property
Private myIdPropertyDefinition As New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, MY_ID, MapiPropertyType.Integer)

'setup the required properties collection
Dim delTaskRequiredProperties As New PropertySet()
delTaskRequiredProperties.Add(myIdPropertyDefinition)

'attempts to load the task from Exchange
Task.Bind(myExchServer, change.ItemId, delTaskRequiredProperties)
```

The credentials being used to in `myExchServer` (an `ExchangeService` object) should be fine, as the same variable is used to perform the `SyncFolderItems` call, which works perfectly.

Do I need to use a different technique than the `Task.Bind()` method to fully load a deleted Task? Or is there an alternative method to use in this situation, to search the `DeletedItems` folder for the specified `ItemId`?

**Edit** - [`ExchangeService.FindItems()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.finditems(v=exchg.80).aspx) method call

I've attempted to find the deleted Task by using the [`ExchangeService.FindItems()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.finditems(v=exchg.80).aspx) method call, with no luck so far. It fails when attempting to add the change.ItemId as a search parameter in exactly the manner [described here](http://www.alnorth.com/fixes/finding-an-appointment-by-id-on-ews/), neither `.ItemId` or `.ItemId.ToString()` are valid search parameters in the SearchFilter object. (The same issue occurs when trying to search with the [`Folder.FindItems()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.finditems(v=exchg.80).aspx) method too)

```
Dim view As ItemView = New ItemView(10)

Dim delTaskRequiredProperties As New PropertySet()
delTaskRequiredProperties.Add(TaskSchema.Id)
delTaskRequiredProperties.Add(myIdPropertyDefinition)

view.PropertySet = delTaskRequiredProperties
view.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow

Dim idSearch As SearchFilter.IsEqualTo = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(TaskSchema.Id, change.ItemId.ToString())

Dim results As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = myExchangeServer.FindItems(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems, New Mailbox(exchangeAccount)), idSearch, view)

For Each item As Item In results

    Debug.WriteLine("itemId==" & change.ItemId.ToString())
    Debug.WriteLine("id==" & item.Id.ToString())
    Debug.WriteLine(item.GetType().ToString())

    For Each exProp As ExtendedProperty In item.ExtendedProperties
        Debug.WriteLine("ex-id==" & exProp.PropertyDefinition.Id)
        Debug.WriteLine("ex-name==" & exProp.PropertyDefinition.Name)
        Debug.WriteLine("ex-value==" & exProp.Value)
    Next

Next
```

---

Or is this just not possible, and do I need to alter my whole approach to linking the two systems, and attempt to store the [CleanGlobalObjectId](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/04e4b222-69e4-40bb-b6c4-3bba9fa446d2/ews-managed-api-syncfolderitems-how-to-update-and-deletekeeping-track-of-items?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)? in my client Task records?

Comment: Out of interest, is there anything else I should add to this question, or try myself first to get a response? Or is EWS just a very quiet part of SO? Thanks, Ted

Comment: Are you sure the tasks you're looking for are in the deleted items folder as opposed to the hard deleted folder. You could try using [EWSEditor](https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/) with the Change.ItemID to ensure you can retrieve that item by ID. That could rule out your Q re using the change ItemID.

Comment: Also, you could try building your propertyset for change items using  `As New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly)` and adding additional properties from there. Some recent EWS work I've been doing against Exchange 2013 had issues as the FirstClassProperties were throwing obscure errors.

Comment: Thanks for the input G. I'd not heard of EWS Editor, and it looks really useful. It's confirmed that the deleted Task is indeed in the Deleted Items folder, and that its UniqueId tallies with the ItemId I'm getting back in the change object. I tried passing in the `BasePropertySet.IdOnly` to the `PropertySet` passed into the `SyncFolderItems()` call, but it didn't alter what was returned in the change object (just the ItemId).

Comment: Any answers or advice (or advice on how to improve my question) would still be appreciated. There's now 24 hours before my 200 beautiful, hard earned reputation points go down the toilet!